# Error bars with Highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts

I am trying to plot some series with errorbars using highcharter and I couldn't find a way to do it efficiently.

Moreover, some of the attributes of the errorbars do not seem to respond while being manipulated from highcharter. (taken from [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cerrorbar%3E)).

For instance,

```
   df <- data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3), c(5,6,7)))

   hchart(t1, "errorbar", 
     y = X2, 
     low = X2 -0.5, 
     high = X2 + 0.5,
     color = 'red',
     stemWidth = 1,
     whiskerLength = 1) %>%
   hc_add_series(data = t1$X2,
            color = "red")
```

When I change the color and whiskerLength arguments of the errorbar series nothing seems to happen in the output.

Please can anyone help me to understand

1) How to plot a series with errorbars efficiently
2) Why some attributes do not seem to work with the API.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2) `hchart` has a different behavior when the argument is a `data.frame`. In that case the `...` arguments are the aesthetic mappings instead of the usual arguments to the series.

1) So, to have more control in what you want you can use just `hc_add_series`:

```
library(dplyr)

highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = list_parse(mutate(df, low = X2 - 0.5, high = X2 + 0.5)),
                type = "errorbar", color = "red", stemWidth = 1,  whiskerLength = 1) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df$X2, color = "red")
```

1.2) Other options is set the parameter of the series via `hc_plotOptions`:

```
hchart(df, "errorbar", 
       y = X2, 
       low = X2 -0.5, 
       high = X2 + 0.5) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = df$X2, color = "red") %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(
    errorbar = list(
      color = "red",
      stemWidth = 1,
      whiskerLength = 1
    )
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! This answers my questions. Thank you very much!